# Access Calculate Next Value (lookup value}?

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I need to get a value from a textbox in a report's detail section which will give me multiple values.  I need to get each of those values into VB to do some calculations...  I can pull a value from forms with ChildID = Forms!FRM_Child!ChildID.Value, but when I put

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim ChildID as Integer
ChildID = Reports!RPT_Due_Date!ChildID.Value
End Sub
```

it crashes and says "Run-time error '2424':  The expression you entered has a field, control, or property name that Microsoft Access can't find."
I've checked and double checked the names.  The thing I figure is that somehow because it's in the detail section with multiple values it crashes.  Any ideas?

```
ChildID  Last_Asmt_Type Last_Asmt_Date  Next_Asmt_Type      Next_Asmt_Date
1        Initial Evaluation 1/5/15      Periodic Review         5/5/15
2        Periodic Review    2/5/15      Annual Review           6/1/15
3        Annual Review      3/5/15      Periodic Review         7/1/15
```

What I want to do is get the Last_Asmt_Type and then with if/then rules select the Next_Asmt_Type  ie If Last_Asmt_Type is Periodic Then Next_Asmt_Type is Annual....

How would I do this with a lookup value?

Comment: What will you do with the result of your calculations? 'cause if you pass it back to the detailsection you might try writing a function and using it in the report instead of grabbing a value on_open ans processing it? I don't think you can grab the value due to the considerations you have: which of the multiple values should ChildMMI become?

Answer (score 0):

In `Report_Open()`, the textbox exists as control, but it has no value yet.
Your code would work in `Report_Load()`, but as you already know, it would be pointless because you would only get the first value.

If you want to read all values, don't try to read them from the report textbox, open a recordset on the report's data source. Like this:

```
Dim RS As Recordset
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Me.RecordSource)
Do While Not RS.EOF
    Debug.Print RS!MMI
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
RS.Close
```

But:
Most probably there is an entirely different and better way to do what you want. What kind of calculations are you doing?